# How to tell if I reach the beginning of a list when using a reverse For Loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, reverse

*I am fairly new to C#, so I'm sorry if this is a simple question*

--

I have a list of stock objects and I am using a for loop to go backwards through the list. Each property of the stock object is set to a textbox to display the value and there is a button that allows the user to cycle through each object, changing the values of the textboxes.

I need to tell if I reach the beginning of the list so that I can deactivate the button that allows the user to go backwards through the list.

**Note** - 
The Count is > 1 because I had to skip the first item in the list.

Here is my code:

```
            if (stockList.Count > 1)
            {

                for (int i = stockList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    txtName.Text = stockList[i].Name;
                    numLastPrice.Value = stockList[i].LastPrice;
                    numOpeningPrice.Value = stockList[i].OpeningPrice;
                    numLowPrice.Value = stockList[i].LowPrice;
                    numHighPrice.Value = stockList[i].HighPrice;

                    if (i == ???)
                    {
                        txtName.Text = stockList[i].Name;
                        numLastPrice.Value = stockList[i].LastPrice;
                        numOpeningPrice.Value = stockList[i].OpeningPrice;
                        numLowPrice.Value = stockList[i].LowPrice;
                        numHighPrice.Value = stockList[i].HighPrice;

                        btnBack.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `i == 0` implies "the first element" (which is visited last) when looping backwards through a 0-based collection; and `i == collection.Count - 1` would the "the last element" in the collection (which is visited first).

Comment: @user2864740 Oh! Okay, I will try that. Sorry, I thought that **i** stood for the iteration and not the index.

Comment: You need to learn how to use the step debugger, then you could have figured this out (and many more problems) pretty easily . Also reading the documentation can save you a lot of tiem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 10 items in that list, then you're going backwards from 9 to 0 (indexes are zero based by default)

In your case, `0` indicates the first item in your list, so just check the index is `0`

```
if (i == 0)
```

---

*(edit after reading comments)*

in your `for` loop you declare `i` as an `int` with the value of `.Count - 1`:

```
for (int i = stockList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

so in your loop `i` is just a variable, but as a result of the way you declared it, it will also be the index value of your list as you iterate through the loop.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following snippet helps you see the relationship between `i` and the list:

```
var myList = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

for (int i = myList.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"i:{i}, myList[{i}]={myList[i]}");
    if (i == 3)
    {
        //I can access the elements at an index different than `i`
        Console.WriteLine($"i:{i}, Seaky peek at the 5th element (index 4): {myList[4]}");
    }
}

// This would cause a compilation error because `i` is being used outside of `for`
//i = 100; // Error: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Console.WriteLine($"First item is myList[0] and is '{myList[0]}'");
Console.WriteLine($"Last item is myList[myLIst.Count()-1] ans is '{myList[myList.Count() - 1]}'");


// Let's go through the list again 
for (int someNameForIndex = myList.Count() - 1; someNameForIndex >= 0; someNameForIndex--)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"i:{someNameForIndex}, myList[{someNameForIndex}]={myList[someNameForIndex]}");
}
```

This generates the following output

```
i:4, myList[4]=E
i:3, myList[3]=D
i:3, Seaky peek at the 5th element (index 4): E
i:2, myList[2]=C
i:1, myList[1]=B
i:0, myList[0]=A
First item is myList[0] and is 'A'
Last item is myList[myLIst.Count()-1] ans is 'E'
i:4, myList[4]=E
i:3, myList[3]=D
i:2, myList[2]=C
i:1, myList[1]=B
i:0, myList[0]=A
```